# Show that if |f(x)| converges in infinity, so is f(x).

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, infinity

[image]

I think that in a I should compare the function |f(x) - f(x) and 2|f(x)| but I am not sure how i would do that.

Also, I am not sure how i should duduce what i want to deduce in b after i find a.

Comment: For part $b$, say that $\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$ converges if $\frac{| \sin x |}{x^2}$ converges, and that the latter converges because $\frac{| \sin x |}{x^2} \le \frac{1}{x^2}$ (implied that there are integrals in front of all these expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (a), use
\begin{equation} 
\left| \int_c^{d} f(x) dx \right | \leq  \int_c^{d} \left| f(x) \right | dx 
\end{equation}

For part (b), use the result of part (1) and $| \sin x| \leq 1$. and the fact that
\begin{equation}
\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} dx
\end{equation}
converges.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove (a). Set
$$
f_+(x)=\max\{f(x),0\},\quad f_-(x)=\max\{-f(x),0\}
$$
Note that $f_+$ and $f_-$ are continuous as well; moreover
$$
f(x)=f_+(x)-f_-(x),\quad |f(x)|=f_+(x)+f_-(x)
$$
Since $0\le f_+(x)\le|f(x)|$, we have, for every $b\ge a$,
$$
0\le \int_a^b f_+(x)\,dx\le\int_a^b |f(x)|\,dx\le\int_a^\infty|f(x)|\,dx
$$
Since the function
$$
F_+(b)=\int_a^b f_+(x)\,dx
$$
is non decreasing and bounded, its limit at $\infty$ exists and is finite. Similarly for
$$
F_-(b)=\int_a^b f_-(x)\,dx
$$
Now
\begin{align}
\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx
&=
\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(\int_a^b f_+(x)\,dx-\int_a^b f_-(x)\,dx\right)
\\[6px]
&=
\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^b f_+(x)\,dx-\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^b f_-(x)\,dx
\end{align}

For part (b), note that
$$
\left|\frac{\sin x}{x^2}\right|\le\frac{1}{x^2}
$$
and that
$$
\int_{1}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx=1
$$